# Why will Appcelerator Studio stop compiling Android titanium app on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows-10, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a clean install of Appcelerator Studio 4.4.0 on Windows 10, Android SDK build tools 21 & 23, Appcelerator CLI 5.1.0, Titanium CLI 5.0.5, Titanium SDK 5.1.2, Java JDK 1.0.8_66, Node.js 0.12.7, npm 2.11.3.  I did install Android Studio with SDK 23 prior to installing Appcelerator Studio.

I'm trying to compile an Android app but the process stops with the following message:

```
Extracting module resources c:\ProgramData\...\titanium-media.res.zip
```

This happens no matter if I try to run on a device or the Android emulator.  I have re-installed Appcelerator Studio from scratch several times but the problem persists.  I have another machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and I compile the same app with no problem at all.

One thing that I have seen in the Dev console is the following message:

```
["Expected ')'","",1]
["Exception thrown and not caught","https://appc-studio.appcelerator.com/js/prototype.js",601]
```

What is wrong with this installation?

EDIT:
The following is the most suspicious set of messages.  The rest seems to be normal:

```
 [INFO] :   Launching emulator: Nexus_5_API_23_x86
[TRACE] :  Starting emulator: Nexus_5_API_23_x86
[TRACE] :  Checking if emulator Nexus_5_API_23_x86 is running...
[TRACE] :  Detecting if Nexus_5_API_23_x86 exists...
[TRACE] :  Found 2 emulators
[TRACE] :  Emulator exists, detecting all running emulators and connected devices...
[TRACE] :  Detected 1 running emulators and connected devices
[TRACE] :  Checking 1 devices to see if it's the emulator we want
[TRACE] :  The emulator is NOT running
[TRACE] :  Emulator not running, detecting running emulators
[TRACE] :  Found 2 emulators
[TRACE] :  Starting the emulator...
[TRACE] :  Scanning ports to find a port for the emulator to listening on
[TRACE] :  Emulator will listen on port 5557
[INFO] :   Running: c:\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe "-avd" "Nexus_5_API_23_x86" "-port" "5557" "-no-boot-anim" "-partition-size" "128" "-sdcard" "C:\Users\Ivan\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_x86.avd\sdcard.img"
[TRACE] :  Emulator is starting, monitoring boot state...
[TRACE] :  Checking the boot state for the next 240000 ms
[TRACE] :  Waiting for emulator to register with ADB
[TRACE] :  Emulator process started
[TRACE] :  offline build file C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Temp\build-0c7e72e7ca552a8e5ab78e0c12606b5de37dbb51.json
[TRACE] :  Found 1 devices, checking if any of them are the emulator...
[TRACE] :  Emulator is running!
[TRACE] :  Checking if boot animation has finished...
[TRACE] :  Emulator is booted, emitting booted event
[INFO] :   Emulator is booted
[INFO] :   SD card not required, skipping mount check
[INFO] :   Emulator ready!
```

and then this:

```
2016-02-03T03:04:15.854Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 0
2016-02-03T03:04:15.886Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  22716
```

Even though the emulator is running Studio launches a new one, and does not connect to the previous one.

Comment: Note: The Dev Console message is not related.

Comment: Are you able to get more information when you run it with trace log level? Use the log leven button in the console view to set the level.

Answer (score 0):

For fear of stating the obvious, have you added the JDK to your PATH variable? (google "appcelerator jdk path windows" and you will find looooads of posts about that)

The only thing which looks different to my (not win10) set up is the JDK? I have 1.7.0_79. I don't know if this may help?

I know that in the past having JDK7 instead of 6 would cause odd, build-time problems so it might be worth looking at.

HTH

Comment: Checked all folders and environment variables according to the Appcelerator Software Locations document and are according to them.  Still the same results.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: the build-manifest.json file under build\android folder was corrupted.  I replaced the file and rebuilt and it worked.  Strange.